# touchpad doesn't tap-click at login screen

Tags: mouse, touchpad, tap-to-click

On every desktop environment, except for the login screen of Ubuntu 12.04, I can just tap the touchpad of my laptop to simulate a mouseclick. Why doesn't it work anymore at the login screen?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1619009&p=10102942#post10102942 ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The two above commands that I entered in terminal were accepted, because when I  enter them again the message ¨ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop': File exists¨ There is no window showing at the login screen after logout.

Comment: Oops... Only just noticed, but that is for `gdm`, not `lightdm`, which is now the default login manager...

Comment: Oh ok I see. Uhm, forgive my ignorance, but does this mean that I have to undo the first two lines, and after that redo them but swap `gdm` with `lightdm` in the command line?

Comment: You don't *have* to, as those lines are in GDM's setup, not lightdm's. It may be a good idea anyway. This question reminded me of an old netbook with no functioning left click button I needed to fix, so I asked [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403113/how-do-you-enable-tap-to-click-via-command-line-with-xmodmap) question...

Comment: I will check that one out. As far as undoing the two commands, I thought it would be a good idea to do so for not making a mess of things. I will try the alternate lines in Terminal.

Comment: `nick@ubuntu:~$ sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-settings-mouse.desktop  
[sudo] password for nick:   
nick@ubuntu:~$ sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop  
nick@ubuntu:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/gnome-settings-mouse.desktop /usr/share/lightdm/autostart/LoginWindow/  
ln: target '/usr/share/lightdm/autostart/LoginWindow/' is not a directory: No such file or directory`      Too bad :(

Comment: If it is currently working fine, and you don't particularly   want to use GNOME in the future, hopefully it will be fine... The problem with the last command may be the final `/`.

Comment: Maybe I'll just give up on this one.. thanks anyway wilf