# How do you enable tap-to-click via command line?

Tags: command-line, touchpad, xmodmap, xinput

You can use this to reverse scroll direction *(natural scroll)*:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12"
```

<sub>You can also set it back again with `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12"`</sub>

and this to switch the left and right buttons:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"
```

<sub>And change it back with `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3"`</sub>

But how do you enable tap to click from command line? Preferably with one command, and not permanently.

<sub>By the way, yes I do know this exists:</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Xmodmap is of no help here. Xmodmap controls physical-to-logical mappings of buttons and keys, not the physical process that generate events in the first place.

The tool for this kind of options is [xinput](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xinput.1.html). The property name depends on your touchpad model, it may be something like

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 0
```

Run `xinput list` to see the names of available devices and `xinput list-props "the device name"` to list properties of a device.

See also [Dynamic Input Configuration with xinput](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Dynamic_Input_Configuration_with_xinput) on the wiki, and [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161420/disabling-one-finger-tap-to-click-but-keep-two-finger-tap-ubuntu-12-04) [examples](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=347944).

Comment: Would I need to restart Unity/Xserver/LightDM to get these to work?

Comment: @wilf No, the command takes effect immediately. You can also configure at least some of these settings via a GUI (in which case they'll be applied when your session starts) but I'm not familiar with the GUI. `gsettings` changes the setting of the GUI interface.

Comment: Hmmm... `0`, `1`, `"1, 0, 0"` don't work with it, but `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" "3"` turns tapping into a back button...

Comment: Success! `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 11` *(might of been that number)* seems to work, though it is also working as a back button AT THE SAME TIME. **Edit:** Whoops, actually, that didn't work - ?!?

Comment: with another device name (in my case: "Glidepoint Virtual Touchpad") the action name would be different then? There is no "tap action" shown at all for my device :(

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Yes, the name of the property may depend on the device. And some touchpads may not have a tap action at all, though I've never encountered one.

Comment: @Gilles, yes mine has, but funnily (well actually, annoyingly), the tap gets deactivated after resuming sleep/hibernation, and currently I have to `sudo service restart glidepoint` to get it back... but I still don't see the corresponding tap action in `xinput list`, so maybe the subject of another question...

Comment: ID-numbers can be used instead of  names. e.g  `xinput set-prop 16 297 1`. 16 is the number of the touchpad from `xinput list`,  297 stands for the "Tapping Enabled" action from `xinput list-props 16`,  1 is `true`.

Comment: @cipricus You can use numbers, but the number can vary from one driver to another. Using the number is mainly useful in scripts when you first parse the input of `list-props` to find a property, and you don't want to deal with complex quoting so you just store the number to use it with `set-prop`.

Comment: @Gilles - Of course, but I guess the name of the device and that of the action varies almost as much as the numbers, so the `list-props` is needed anyway. Furthermore, for some reason, using the name of the action within the command, as suggested by the main answer, wouldn't work for me (`xinput set-prop ""AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Tapping Enabled" 1`), while using just the name of the device did work (`xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" 297 1`).

Comment: for me it's the ``libinput Tapping Enabled'' option

Answer (score 14):

You can use `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

Which enables tap to click.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
```

Will disable it.  This is the same as changing it in System Settings.

Comment: Well, doing it with `xmodmap` could be useful - this is for a battered old netbook with no functioning left click key... but I also thought if I used `xmodmap`, I could enable it in the login screen as well...

Comment: I'm sure it's not possible @wilf. xmodmap controls physical-to-logical mappings of buttons and keys, not the physical process that generate events in the first place.

Comment: If it's just the mirror of what's available in the graphical menu, it will not work in case the option is not visible graphically... (I get the error: `« org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad » does not exist`)

Comment: This answer is much preferred over `xinput`, and if you are using Cinnamon you'll want to adjust accordingly like `gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad false`.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the [main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/403141/47206), given that I had to modify some of the instructions there:

The command to enable tap-to-click is therefore of the form:

```
xinput set-prop "device" "action" 1
```

To read the "device" you have to do

```
xinput list
```

But it may prove difficult to identify the device in that list. Some tips: it is probably under "Virtual core pointer"; it may contain terms like "Syn", "Synaptics", "Touchpad", "Alps", "Glidepoint". e.g., mine was `AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=16`, but I had to guess; as I was not sure I have tested if that was the correct ID number by disabling/enabling the touchpad with `xinput --disable 16` and `xinput --enable 16`.

Now, to get rid of all the confusing names, **ID-numbers can be used instead of the device and action names.**

So, to read the "action":

```
xinput list-props 16
```

Which listed among others:

```
    libinput Tapping Enabled (297): 0
```

So, using ID numbers instead of names, the final command was:

```
xinput set-prop 16 297 1
```

---

Note: for some reason, using the name of the action within the command, as suggested by the main answer, wouldn't work for me (`xinput set-prop ""AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Tapping Enabled" 1`), while using just the name of the device did work (`xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" 297 1`).

---

This command can be useful in systems where there is no GUI for such setting, like in the LXQT that I was testing at the date of the post.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

When setting the `Synaptics Tap Action` value using `xinput`, you may need to specify a sequence of numbers. For example, to get normal primary and secondary tap functionality on my Logitech touchpad, I had to do this:

```bash
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 \ 
    "Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650" \
    "Synaptics Tap Action" 1 1 1 2 1 3
```

I believe this means:

```
1 1 1 2 1 3
: :
1 1 - enable single-finger tap and assign it to Button1 (left-click)
    : :
    1 2 - enable double-finger tap and assign it to Button2 (right-click)
        : :
        1 3 - enable gesture for middle-click and assign it to Button3 (middle-click)
```

Comment: this worked on my xps 9510, thank you.