# Lubuntu 18.10 How to activate tap to click

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad

I'm using a fresh install 18.10 on my Samsung Serie 5 Ultra 530U3C A0L notebook.

I really enjoy the Linux experience so far and everything I need works out of the box for me. The only thing missing is tap to click. How can I activate it? I looked for an option in lxqt but couldnt find one.
I googled a bit and found this: synclient tapbutton1=1 but typing this in the terminal did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you enable tap-to-click via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403113/how-do-you-enable-tap-to-click-via-command-line)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1057274/47206

Answer (score 26, accepted):

this works for me
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Touchpad_configuration

create:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf
```

content:

```
Section "InputClass"   
  Identifier "touchpad"  
  Driver "libinput"  
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"  
  Option "Tapping" "on"  
EndSection
```

and finally

```
reboot
```

**EDIT 06/07/2022** works in Lubuntu 22.04 (presumably works from Lubuntu 20.04 onwards):

1. Open "Keyboard and Mouse Settings"
2. Scroll down to "Mouse and Touchpad"
3. Click on "Device:", select your touchpad (e.g., SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad)
4. Check "Tap to click"
5. Select "Apply"

[Screenshot final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJYy.jpg)

[Source](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/tap-to-click-on-laptop-not-working-in-20-04/969/2)

Comment: This got the right click functionality on my touchpad working. Thanks

Comment: This got one, two, and three fingers clicks working. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 19):

**Activating [tap-to-click](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tapping.html#tap-to-click-default-setting) with xinput via command line**

1. Find your device id (in my case 13 bellow ):

   ```
   # xinput list
   ```

   Look for:

   ```
   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ```
2. Find the "Tapping" desired option code (in my case 283 bellow):

   ```
   # xinput list-props 13
   ```

   Look for:

   ```
   libinput Tapping Enabled (283): 0
   ```
3. Activate it with "1" using:

   ```
   # xinput set-prop 13 283 1
   ```
4. List props once more to confirm:

   ```
   # xinput list-props 13
   ```

   Look for:

   ```
   libinput Tapping Enabled (283): 1
   ```

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Via_xinput)

Comment: This method would be better as it does not require to make any new file or something. At first, worked for me. But after I reboot, I have the same problem again. Something is missing. Its not permanent.

Comment: @Wings https://askubuntu.com/questions/20298/how-to-make-xinput-settings-persist-after-devices-are-unplugged-replugged-and

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that was already available in 18.10, but in 20.04 there is a setting for that (see *Touchpad* > *Tap to Click*):

[image]