# Touchpad is not behaving as it used to be in Ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, laptop, asus, multi-touch

Touchpad is not behaving as it used to be, at least not to what I've been accustomed to.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- boot either **kubuntu** or **lubuntu** Live-CD 20.04 and
- use the touchpad after GUI started

I'd expect that the touchpad's behavior would be similiar to the [standard touchpad behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-touchpad-use-and-settings-6c32fd32-23f4-c2d3-a3f9-cfc70feff233), at least some/most of them.

However, nothing works that way:

- **left-click** by tap one finger anywhere on the touchpad,
- **right-click** by tap two fingers anywhere on the touchpad
- **drag/move** an item by tap, immediately tap and hold, then drag
- etc...

Tried on both of my Lenovo and Asus laptops.

Is it only me or it is happening to you as well?

Comment: It is not happening to me ;-)

Comment: Did you enable tap-to-click?

Comment: That might be what I'm missing @Hi-Angel, how pls?

Comment: @Pilot6, are you running Live-CD 20.04 as-is, or your own system?

Comment: Yes, I ran a 20.04 LiveUSB on many systems. It is not guaranteed that multitouch support works on every hardware. Some touchpads are not supported yet.

Comment: @xpt I assume you're using Gnome. It should be somewhere in settings, but you can also enable from a terminal [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/403115/266507)

Comment: Ah, in settings it is at path: `Mouse & touchpad → Tap to Click`